# woocommerce - get_image_size() deprecated

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Today I've updated my woocommerce plugin and get a **fatal error** on:

```
$woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_width' )
```

I'm using it in a hook function to get the placeholder width:

```
function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog',
                       $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0 ) {

    global $post, $woocommerce;
    $placeholder_width = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_width' );

        ...
}
```

According to this [support entry](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201698639-Woocommerce-Brands-Call-to-undefined-method-WooCommerce-get-image-size-?locale=en-us) the get_image_size function seems to be deprecated, but relacing it with:

```
wcgetimagesize('shopthumbnailimagewidth');
```

returns the same error. **Which function I have to use instead?**

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: In order to learn something here, it would be nice to get an explanation of the downvote... Thanks

Comment: Hint: [help] :-) I think it is expected that older users should know the site's policies

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks for the hint ;) Just read this related meta: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/downvoting-of-woocommerce-related-questions, If the question could be answered from an more experianced user, I don't really see a reason to downvote it. Why not remove the tag, if such questions are not desirable?

Comment: @PieterGoosen ok read yours: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/woocommerce-questions-flooding-wpse, but is this really a downvote? Don't understand it...

Comment: Go and support the [woocommerce proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80132/woocommerce) :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Not really an answer to my question, but thanks! Since it's official part of wordpress, might be better to integrate it here, until the proposal starts ;) Regardless, thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is deprecated in latest version.

You should use this code to get the width:

```
$size = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_catalog' );
$placeholder_width = $size['width'];
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, thanks again Syed. Unfortunately some users downvote woocommerce questions...

Comment: Yes because plugins are off topic and not specific to WordPress. There's tens of thousands of them.

Comment: @BradDalton Ok, thanks. I'll never asking a question about plugins again.

Comment: hahaha. Know how you feel!

Comment: There is a tag for them. The question was NOT generic. It was specific to a plugin, yes - but it was also easily answered and quite relevant. Why? "WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and administrators to ask questions about: theme and plugin development"

Comment: @Aibrean I've already asked why not removing the tag, no answer. See the comments below the question. There is already a heavy blown discussion on meta here, if you are interested, start here: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/woocommerce-questions-flooding-wpse

Comment: Well @poor the question was very useful in my improving my plugin that's in the WP repository.